# Splitting data returned by a command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to split a single line containing multiple words separated by spaces returned by a command. I tried using `read` but it acts completely strange. For example:

Why does running `echo "Hello World!" | read -ra lines; echo "${lines[@]}"` in Bash results in an empty line, but running `echo "Hello World!" | read -ra lines; do echo "${lines[@]}"; done` results in `Hello World!`?

If I run `echo "Hello World!" | tee /dev/stdout | read -ra lines; echo "${lines[@]}"` it also results in an empty line.

Even simple `echo "Hello World!" | read hello; echo "$hello"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The second example has a typo. It should be `echo "Hello World!" | while read -ra lines; do echo "${lines[@]}"; done`